# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting this exception,when deploying my application on server.

```
     enterCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not      autowire field: private com.indus.training.service.EmployeeService com.indus.training.controller.TeamController.empService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.indus.training.dao.EmployeeDAO com.indus.training.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.empDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.indus.training.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.indus.training.init.WebAppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 56 more
```

this is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.indus.training.struts</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringHibernateStrutsProject</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<url>http://training.indus.com</url>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.21</mysql.connector.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <!-- DB related dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet API and JSTL -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>SpringHibernateStrutsProject</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <!-- <webResources>WebContent/WEB-INF/</webResources> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: have you added mysql jdbc jar?

Comment: i have mysql-connector-java.jar in maven,that's the one right?

Comment: By any chance, are you deploying to JBoss AS? And show us your dependency configuration please (or better, check `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` for version conflicts yourself).

Comment: @PavelHoral point, but exception clearly says that class is not found,well yes it might be a version missmatch issue as well.

Comment: What version of hibernate are you including in your app?

Comment: @JohnAment i am using hibernate 4.2.0 as you can see in my pom.xml file

Comment: @PavelHoral hi i have posted my pom.xml config file

Comment: @aniketsuthar Why do you have conflicting versions of hibernate-core in your POM? Its the beginning of your dependencies... you should always check for such things if you get strange class loading issues.

Comment: Also things like `javax.servlet.jsp-api` should always be defined as `provided`. If you include these in your package you are going straight for conflicts with your application server dependencies.

Comment: And I doubt you need to define such dependencies as javassist or cglib. These should be fetched as transitive dependencies if you are not using them directly.

Comment: Well, I pulled in your pom.xml and tried it locally.  the dialect class is present in your output.  I think we need more info.  Do you have logs from your app server?  It may be easier to gist them than try to post into the SO question.