# ClassNotFoundException (class PostgreSQLDialect not found) when trying to deploy Spring app on Tomcat server

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

When I try to run my project on Tomcat server, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Full error stack:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private family.service.ContactService family.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private family.dao.ContactDAO family.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory family.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private family.service.ContactService family.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private family.dao.ContactDAO family.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory family.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private family.dao.ContactDAO family.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory family.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private family.dao.ContactDAO family.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory family.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory family.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory family.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1548)
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.constructDialect(DialectFactory.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:99)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect 
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
...
```

I got this problem when I tried to follow this tutorial:
[Tutorial:Create Spring 3 MVC Hibernate 3 Example using Maven in Eclipse](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/)

I am using Hibernate 3.6.9-Final, Spring 4. (I can switch to Spring 3, if it matters. I just took the Spring dependencies from another project.)

What I have tried:

- To search from Google whether I have a missing Maven dependency. Class org.hibernate.dialect seems to be provided by Hibernate, and I have hibernate-core in my pom.xml. I tried to add hibernate-entitymanager, hibernate-tools, etc. to pom.xml in hope that one of them provides the necessary dependency, but it did not help.
- I thought maybe I need to add PostgreSQL driver, so I added 9.1-901-1.jdbc4 to pom.xml (see below). It did not have an effect.
- I tried to see if Eclipse can resolve class org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect, and indeed, it can. (I took random project file and created entity field of PostgreSQLDialect and CTRL+clicked on the field, and I was taken to source code of class org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect). But I still get errors when I try to run the project on server.
- I tried to inspect Maven depencency tree, as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495802/invocation-of-init-method-failed-nested-exception-is-org-hibernate-hibernateexc). I did not get smarter from looking at it, but it is provided at the end of this post, maybe it helps someone to answer.

### spring-servlet.xml

As instructed in the tutorial, I created spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="family" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

     <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### jdbc.properties

Also, I created jdbc.properties, which includes the line (other lines not provided, as they contain passwords):

```
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

### pom.xml

I have the following POM file (as the tutorial did not provide a POM file, I combined the POM file as good as I could from different sources):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0.M6</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.0</version> 
                </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

### maven dependency tree

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose

[INFO] test:test:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate
)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitte
d for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted f
or duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted fo
r duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitte
d for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted f
or duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted for
duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted f
or duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted fo
r duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omit
ted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted for
 duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted f
or duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted fo
r duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted for
 duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted f
or duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted
 for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.0.RC1:compile - omitted fo
r duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.9.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile

[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - version managed from 1.
6.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Fin
al:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901-1.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  +- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test - omitted for conflict wit
h 1.3)
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    \- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test - omitted for duplicate)
```

**UPDATE:**

Al Sweetman proposed that the problem was that the JAR-s were not getting package into the WAR. We checked with one co-worker:

1. I ran "mvn package" on the project (from command line)
2. I put the created WAR (test-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war) into Tomcat (C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps)
3. I ran startup.bat from command line

In Tomcat log I see the same error: PostgreSQLDialect not found.

Tomcat has unpacked the WAR file. If I look in directory:
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\test-1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib

I see that the file postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar is bundled nicely. I have no idea why the project does not find the JAR file when reading spring-servlet.xml...

**UPDATE2:**
All necessary JARs seem to be present:

[image]

**UPDATE3:**
I changed the PostgreSQL database to a H2 database and now it starts to work without errors.

I also removed the JARs from Run Configurations -> Classpath, because now they seemed to have no effect.

But if I remove the Maven Dependencies from Deployment Assembly, then I get the error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener. So this was also part of the solution. Anyway, now everything works (unless I ever want to use PostgreSQL again :) )

Comment: Is the hibernate jar file present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Assuming you're running the server from within Eclipse/STS: it's worth checking the Servers Launch Configuration to make sure the postgres jar is attached as a dependency.  I've often found a difference between the "editor" classpath and the "server runtime" classpath.

1. Click "Run"
2. Click "Run Configurations"
3. Click "Apache Tomcat" and select your configuration/server
4. Click the "classpath" tab.  You can then try adding the postgres jar manually via the "Add Jars" button after selecting "User Entries"

ANOTHER IDEA

There is another configuration that can be used - I think I may have gotten the wrong Eclipse window (normally and IntelliJ user).

Try the following

1. Right-click on the Eclipse project
2. Select "properties"
3. Select "Deployment Assembly"
   [image: Deployment Assembly]
4. Check the list of JARs for hibernate and postgres.
5. If not there, click "Add"
6. Choose "Archive Via Path Variable"[image: Deployment Assembly Extension]
7. Select "M2_REPO" and from the list that drops down find the jars in your repo for postgres and hibernate.

Then click finish.

I think what was happening was that the jar files weren't being bundled into the war at war creation time.

Comment: When I clicked "Add JARs", I could only add JARs from projects. I instead clicked "Add External JARs" and could add from filesystem. I added postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql/9.1-901-1.jdbc4. Is this what You meant? I still get the same error.

Comment: That is what I meant, my apologies. Can you try adding the hibernate jar file as well?

Comment: Adding hibernate.jar to classpath seems to have helped: I now get another error :) I will try to fix this, too, and if I cannot, I will ask new question. SEVERE: Servlet /test threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException

Comment: Another idea -  I think I may have gotten the wrong Eclipse window (normally and IntelliJ user).

Try the following

1. Right-click on the Eclipse project
2. Select "properties"
3. Select "Deployment Assembly"
4. Check the list of JARs for hibernate and postgres.
5. If not there, click "Add"
6. Choose "Archive Via Path Variable"
7. Select "M2_REPO" and from the list that drops down find the jars in your repo for postgres and hibernate.

Then click finish.

I think what was happening was that the jar files weren't being bundled into the war at war creation time.

Comment: This is all very confusing to me, as I am new to Java EE world. I tried the alternative variant (deleted JARs from Run Configuration and added them to Deployment Assembly), but then I got the same error as before (PostgreSQLDialect not found). Now I added the manually downloaded JARs back to Run Configuration and deleted them from Deployment Assembly, and I get new error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager. This is strange, because just a moment ago I was getting error of not finding org.dom4j.DocumentException!

Comment: PS. @AlSweetman, how did You understand that the JARs were not being bundled into the war file? How can I check this myself next time?

Comment: Bitter experience :-) Losing countless hours myself.  As for telling next time, from checking [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/172866/550210/#msg_550210) I believe checking for the "<attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>" gives an indication as to whether or not it's going to be bundled or not - the presence of that tag means it's going to be included in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Actually, adding hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar to Runtime Configuration fixed this problem. Now I got another error, so I also added dom4j-1.6.1.jar to Runtime Configuration. Now I am getting another error :) Is this going to ever end? :P

Comment: My mistake, it does not work. Updated my original post and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions of Al Sweetman helped, but I got getting new errors and errors (ClassNotFoundExceptions).

So in addition to Al Sweetman's suggestion I also added Maven Dependencies to Java Build Path. <strike>After that I did not get any errors!</strike> Actually I was mistaken. I looked that the server started working, but it still threw the same errors. Adding Maven Dependencies to Java Build Path did not have any effect.

**UPDATE**
I changed the PostgreSQL database to H2 database, and now everything works. But I still needed to add Maven Dependencies to Deployment Assembly, so this was part of solution.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ahhh nice one @Rauni!  Well done sir. Just checking my project - I have those Maven Dependencies present in the Order/Export too.

I'll be interested to see what happens if you leave those as "export" and remove the entries from the Deployment Assembly.

Bet you're feeling satisfied now... :)

Comment: Eh, @AlSweetman, it did not help :) see my edit. I looked into the problem with one co-worker and I will update my original post with some information of what we found.